# Batch script to delete all the subfolders inside specific folder in all remote servers and output as a text file

Tags: batch-file

Here I am trying to execute a batch script which deletes subfolders under folder "updates" in all remote machines. List of servers are passed as input
(serverlist.txt)

```bash
echo off
for /f %%l in (C:\deleteauto\delrem\serverlist.txt) do
if exist C:\updates goto sub
if not exist C:\updates goto nofile

:sub
del /f /q "C:\updates\*.*"
for /d %%d in ("C:\updates\*.*") do rmdir /s /q "%%d"
echo folder is deleted in %%l >>c:\finaloutput.txt

:nofile
echo No folders in %%l >>c:\final output.txt
```

Can someone please help in rectifying the errors. Script executed but outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```bash
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (C:\deleteauto\delrem\serverlist.txt) do (
    if exist "\\%%l\C$\updates" (
        pushd "\\%%l\C$\updates"
        del /f /q "*."
        for /d %%d in ("*.") do rmdir /s /q "%%d"
        echo Folder is deleted on server: %%l>>finaloutput.txt
        popd
    ) else (
        echo Folder does not exist on server: %%l>>finaloutput.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you friend, that was quite useful, But I had to modify some changes to the above code because it was deleting the contents in the server where I am logged in., Upon changing few of the lines to the below , It worked absolutely as expected. Thank you for your timely help.

Comment: I will post the modified working script as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I may tackle the task:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "SvrLst=C:\deleteauto\delrem\serverlist.txt"

If Not Exist "%SvrLst%" GoTo :EOF
(For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("%SvrLst%"
    ) Do PushD "%%~G\C$\updates" 2>NUL && (
        RD /S /Q . 2>NUL
        Echo Instruction to empty directory applied on %%~G & PopD
    ) || Echo Directory path not found on %%~G) 1>"C:\finaloutput.txt"
```

You will note that I have not stated that the directory was emptied. Just because an instruction was applied, does not mean that it was successful at doing so. Unless you check that the `\C$\updates` directory is completely empty afterwards, you should not imply that it is.

Comment: @AnneCarolineGloryPrince, how about, for future readers, you run the code, and provide feedback on it. I say that because, whilst you're free to accept any answer you want, future readers may prefer to use a more robust and speedy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Errors were rectified by @Fire Fox , Thank you! Modified slightly & it worked as expected.
Code:

```bash
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (C:\deleteauto\delrem\serverlist.txt) do (
    if exist "\\%%l\C$\updates" (
        pushd "\\%%l\C$\updates"
        del /f /q "\\%%l\C$\updates\*.*"
        for /d %%d in ("\\%%l\C$\updates\*.*") do rmdir /s /q "%%d"
        echo Folder is deleted on server: %%l>>C:\finaloutput.txt
        popd
    ) else (
        echo Folder does not exist on server: %%l>>C:\finaloutput.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: There are no fixes here for the answer by Fire Fox. All you have done is to replace `.` with `\\%%l\C$\updates`, when it wasn't needed, and to change the location of the output file to the end users PC, as opposed the the single and better location in the executors system drive.